# How to convert Image with just one band to featureCollection and then export as shape

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level1")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Guyana'));

Map.centerObject(roi, 6);
Map.addLayer(roi,{},"roi",0)

var giri = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/MANGROVE_FORESTS').select('1')
Map.addLayer(giri, {palette: ['yellow']}, 'giri',1);

// Reude to image from imagecollection
var img = giri.mosaic().clip(roi)
Map.addLayer(img, {palette: ['yellow']}, 'img',0);

// Image to FeatureCollection
var vectors = img.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 1000,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'zone',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
});

Map.addLayer(vectors, {palette: ['yellow']}, 'vectors',1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which band you want as featureCollection, but to export as shapefile, try this

```
Export.table.toDrive({
collection:vectors,
description: 'mangroves',
fileFormat: 'SHP',
});
```

To increase the precision, I would suggest:

```
// Image to FeatureCollection
var vectors = img.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 30,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: false,
  bestEffort: true,
  labelProperty: 'zone',
  maxPixels:1e8,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! @jurquiza, It did improve resolution but is their any workaround for this? I still get many pixels that are completely ignored while converting to vector.

Comment: I updated my answer adding **maxPixels:1e8** argument, it is the maximum number of pixels that can be reduced in GEE. In this [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f6f097915349e2c7b35361a06528c3c9) you can see the differences using or not this argument.   If you find it useful, consider mark the answer as accepted for future references.

Comment: Thanks much @jurquiza!